# parallelUploads:10 calling multiple times success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am using following configuration for dropzone I am uploading multiple files simultaneously
On server It is uploading all files at once and then sending response to client.
But problem is on client site it is calling multiple times(no of files uploaded) success function.

I want success function should execute once

My code is

```
$("i#dzopen").dropzone({
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        url: 'UploadImages',
        previewsContainer: "#media-upload-previews",
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 10,
        maxFiles: 20,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*,audio/*,video/*",
        init: function() {
            this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                alert("again");
                console.log("log "+responseText);
                $.each(responseText, function(k, v) {
                    console.log("l path " + v.largePicPath);
                    console.log("s path " + v.smallPicPath);
                    console.log("height " + v.imgHeight + " wid " + v.imgWidth);
                });
                console.log(file);
                alert('uploded ' + file.name);

            });
        }
    });
```

I tried code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/m51wbb9c/1/)**

Multiple upload is working properly but it is executing success function multiple times how to get all image response at once.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `success`, you should use `successmultiple` to detect all successful uploads.

```
`this.on("successmultiple", function(file, responseText) {
```

For more info:
http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-successmultiple